# How to recreate the following signs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows, arrows

Gidday,

I work as a professional dog trainer and I am currently working on some new courses. I write all of my documents, e.g. lessons plans, reports, ... using LaTeX, but my knowledge of TikZ is very limited and I need some help getting me started on recreating some of the signs used in *Rally Obedience*. Easy geometric shapes are no problem, but I can't figure out how to create bent arrows or a cone.

[image]

There are quite a few signs with arrows at different angles.

[image]

And then there are complex signs like this one above.

I would like to be able to recreate signs like this and also modify them to my needs. If someone could help me get started on this one it would be greatly appreciated. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using the wrong tool here.  For complex design, it would be wise to use vector graphics software, e.g. Inkscape, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to give you one starting point consider this code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lmodern} 


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \draw[line width=1.5cm,-stealth,green] (3,-3)--(3,3) arc (0:270:3)--(9,0);
        \node[font=\fontsize{52}{58}\sffamily\bfseries] at (2.5,-2.5) () {270° LEFT};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and this output:

[image]

**EDIT:**
This is more close at your request:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \draw[line width=1.5cm,-stealth,green] (3,-3)--(3,3) arc (0:270:3 and 2)--(9,1);
        \node[font=\fontsize{52}{58}\sffamily\bfseries] at (2.5,-2.5) () {270° LEFT};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**GIFT:**

\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,lmodern}

\begin{document}

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thin]
    \filldraw[fill=cyan!60] (2.6,4.2) arc (0:180:2.6);
    \filldraw[fill=white] (2,4.2) arc (0:181:2);% <<-- why 181 and not 180? question for you
    \filldraw[fill=cyan!60] (2.6,4.2)--(2.8,4.2)--(2.3,3.8)--(1.8,4.2)--(2,4.2);
    \filldraw[fill=white] (-2,4.2)--(-2.3,4.4)--(-2.6,4.2);
    \filldraw[fill=cyan!60] (-2.6,4)--(-2.8,4)--(-2.3,4.3)--(-1.8,4)--(-2,4);
    \filldraw[fill=cyan!60] (-2,4)--(-2,0)--(-2.6,0)--(-2.6,4);
    \filldraw[fill=cyan!60] (2,3.9)--(2.3,3.7)--(2.6,3.9)--(2.6,0)--(2.8,0)--(2.3,-.4)--(1.8,0)--(2,0)--(2,3.9);
    \node at (0,5) () {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{delimitatore stradale.png}};
    \node[font=\fontsize{22}{24}\sffamily\bfseries] at (0,0.5) () {Turn back!};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{document}

[image]

Comment: Oh, that was way easier than expected. I totally forgot about `arc`. Thanks heaps!